# Calculate time difference between unique rows of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, calculated-columns

Suppose I have a table that has two fields. `Record_Created` is a `datetime` and `Action` is just a string. The data may look like this:

```
Record_Created      Action
1/11/18 5:24 PM     Action 1
1/11/18 5:32 PM     Action 2
1/17/18 4:41 PM     Action 3
1/17/18 4:41 PM     Action 2
1/17/18 4:44 PM     Action 3
1/18/18 11:12 AM    Action 4
1/18/18 11:12 AM    Action 3
1/18/18 11:13 AM    Action 4
1/25/18 2:44 PM     Action 5
```

I need to calculate the time difference (in days) between different actions, but not just between individual rows, but rather unique actions based on the last occurrence of each action. So my result data set should look like this:

```
Action  Difference
Action 2    6
Action 3    1
Action 4    0
Action 5    7
```

What's the best and most efficient way to achieve this considering I have over a million records in this table to go go through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to look at the last date per action and then list the actions sorted by that date and show the time span in days from one action to the next one.

So aggregate by action to get the last date and then use `LAG` to look into the previous record.

```
select 
  action, 
  max(record_created),
  date_diff(day,
    lag(max(record_created)) over (order by max(record_created)),
    max(record_created)
  ) as diff;
from actions
group by action
order by action;
```

This query also incudes the first action (with difference = null), but I guess you don't mind.

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/EAA26233

Comment: Hi Thorsten, yes you're right on. This is exactly what I need. This was just for a sub-set of records in a table. Say I have something like ProductID in this same table and want to also group actions within ProductID, I just need to add ProductID to the GROUP BY clause, so it looks like.....GROUP BY PoductID, Action?

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct. `select productid, action, ... group by productid, action`.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this code only works on sub-set of records, not the entire dataset. For example, if I added productid to the temp table, I only get the time difference calculated for the 1st set of ProductID's. I just added ProductID to your temp table and inserted 2 more groups of products with the same exact dates: http://rextester.com/QCET45072

Comment: Made a small change and it *sort of* works (http://rextester.com/JMUI80775) but the day difference in the very first record in each subset is understandably calculated wrongly because it looks at the very last record of the previous sub-set. Now I'm fairly confident that the 1st record must exist in each sub-set so I can just populate it with 0, but I'm curious if there's a clever way of only making this calculation within the same sub-set of data (in my case just within the same ProductID)?

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. When grouping by `productid, action`, then you must add a partion clause, i.e. change `over (order by max(record_created))` to `over(partition by productid order by max(record_created))`.

Comment: Very nice Thorsten. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

You could take the minimal and maximal dates for each action type and use [`datediff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) to get the number of days between them:

```
SELECT   action, DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(record_created), MAX(record_created))
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY action
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: It's not so easy unfortunately. Read the request again. It's about the last date per action and the time spans between these. This is why Action 5 is shown with seven days difference (to action 4).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are getting action 5

```
declare @T table (dt datetime, action varchar(10));
insert into @T values 
       ('1/11/18 5:24 PM',  'Action 1')
     , ('1/11/18 5:32 PM',  'Action 2')
     , ('1/17/18 4:41 PM',  'Action 3')
     , ('1/17/18 4:41 PM',  'Action 2')
     , ('1/17/18 4:44 PM ', 'Action 3')
     , ('1/18/18 11:12 AM', 'Action 4')
     , ('1/18/18 11:12 AM', 'Action 3')
     , ('1/18/18 11:13 AM', 'Action 4')
     , ('1/25/18 2:44 PM',  'Action 5');

select * from @t order by action, dt desc

select tt.action, tt.dt, tt.leaddt, DATEDIFF(day, tt.leaddt, tt.dt) as diff 
  from ( select t.* 
              , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t.action order by t.dt desc) as rn 
              , lead(t.dt)   over (partition by t.action order by t.dt desc) as leaddt 
           from @T t 
       ) tt
where tt.rn = 1 
  and tt.leaddt is not null 
order by tt.action

dt                      action
----------------------- ----------
2018-01-11 17:24:00.000 Action 1
2018-01-17 16:41:00.000 Action 2
2018-01-11 17:32:00.000 Action 2
2018-01-18 11:12:00.000 Action 3
2018-01-17 16:44:00.000 Action 3
2018-01-17 16:41:00.000 Action 3
2018-01-18 11:13:00.000 Action 4
2018-01-18 11:12:00.000 Action 4
2018-01-25 14:44:00.000 Action 5

action     dt                      leaddt                  diff
---------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------
Action 2   2018-01-17 16:41:00.000 2018-01-11 17:32:00.000 6
Action 3   2018-01-18 11:12:00.000 2018-01-17 16:44:00.000 1
Action 4   2018-01-18 11:13:00.000 2018-01-18 11:12:00.000 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it's not exactly the result I'm looking for.

Comment: Apologies if I was not clear. You're missing the difference between latest Action 4 and Action 5 in your result set.

Answer (score 0):

This might be kind of brute force solution, but it should do the job. Logic is 
1. Get Max date for each of actions
2. Assign Row Numbers to each of the records so you can iterate over in a subquery.
3.Calculate the difference

```
;WITH cte1 as
(select action, max(record_created) as MaxDt, ROW_Number() OVER(Order by Action) as row_num
 from @YourTable
 group by action
) 

select *, (select DATEDIFF(DAY, b.MaxDT, a.MaxDT) 
            from cte1 b 
           where b.row_num= a.row_num-1 ) as Diff
from cte1 a
```